# how to get the url(URL is in canonical) without querystring values in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, url, query-string

Is there any way to get current url (which is in the form of canonical) without query string?
One option is to use Request.Rawurl but I need the better solution to get the url which is canonical form.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is what you are after, but running locally this would return 'http://localhost'

```
   var t = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
   var newurl = t.Replace(HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "");
```

Comment: http://localhost/TestProject/test.html?id=10
I'm expecting below url

http://localhost/TestProject/test.html

But I get 
http://localhost/Test/default.aspx